# Grunt Concurrent cannot run too many tasks on DigitalOcean machine

Tags: gradle, gruntjs

I have an application built with JHipster which builds and runs ok in my notebook. However, now that I'm trying to build it in a DigitalOcean (small) droplet, grunt is first warning about the few cores and later failing. What should I do about it?

```
Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task
>> Warning: There are more tasks than your concurrency limit. After this limit
>> is reached no further tasks will be run until the current tasks are
>> completed. You can adjust the limit in the concurrent task options
:grunt_build FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':grunt_build'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 137
```

Comment: Well, if you only have one virtual CPU on your droplet, I don't see how you can get around this. Concurrency only works with multiple cores by definition. Otherwise everything is justing waiting in line for the CPU to be free.

Comment: I wouldn't bother to wait, the problem is that the task is being killed.